# Getting error with JMeter 3.2 CookieHandler: Unable to add the cookie error

Tags: performance, testing, jmeter, ruby-jmeter

I have currently Jmeter 3.2 installed on my Mac (macOS Sierra). Now I want to install 3.1 because of the `jmeter ERROR o.a.j.p.h.c.HC4 CookieHandler: Unable to add the cookie` error.

How can I install an older version via home brew. I did `brew install jmeter -3.1` but that doesn't work.

Comment: What brew search jmeter returns?

Comment: Unfortunately brew formula for JMeter does not support installing a specific version of JMeter, it only installs whatever is hard-coded in the formula (currently it's 3.2: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/master/Formula/jmeter.rb)

Comment: You could run `brew edit jmeter`, change it to 3.1 and run your local formula. Check FAQ: https://docs.brew.sh/FAQ.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try working this around by adding the next line to *user.properties* file

```
CookieManager.check.cookies=false
```

JMeter restart will be required to pick the property up. Also you can try playing with different `Cookie Policy` values:

[image: Cookie Policy Values JMeter Cookie Manager]

See [Using the HTTP Cookie Manager in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-http-cookie-manager-jmeter-not-cookie-jar) for more details.

---

If you still want to run JMeter 3.1 (or any other version available in [JMeter Archives](https://archive.apache.org/dist/jmeter/)) you don't need to "install" it, JMeter is a Java-based application so it will be quite enough to download, unpack and run it. Given you use `brew` I believe you're using MacOSX, steps in "Terminal" application would look like:

1. `wget http://apache.claz.org//jmeter/binaries/apache-jmeter-3.1.tgz`
2. `tar xf apache-jmeter-3.1.tgz`
3. `cd apache-jmeter-3.1/bin/`
4. `./jmeter.sh`